# Blank screen when running pyglet from wine

Tags: python-2.7, pyglet, wine

I recently installed wine on my Ubuntu computer, and can't seem to properly configure pyglet.

I have Python 2.7 installed, and I can successfully import pyglet, but drawing anything to the window results in a black screen.

I'm using the latest stable version of wine (I think it's 3.0), pyglet 1.3.2, and Python 2.7.

Running pyglet without wine works perfectly.

I'm launching my interpreter with the command:
    wine ~/.wine/drive_c/python27/python.exe

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it stay blank while you move the cursor in the window or press a keyboard key? Can you start other GL applications via wine and they work? Also, what's the reason behind running the project through wine, maybe there's a better solution to your actual problem?

Comment: The window stays blank even if I move the cursor into the window or hit a keyboard key. I'll have to test some other GL applications to see if they run correctly. I'm using wine because I'm trying to convert the file into a Windows executable with pyinstaller later, and I don't have Windows available.

Comment: I see, If you want a quick solution, I'd suggest `qemu-img create -f qcow2 win10.qcow2 40G` and then `qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -machine q35,accel=kvm -device intel-iommu -cpu host -mem 4096 -cdrom ~/Downloads/win10.iso -drive file=win10.qcow2,format=qcow2 -boot order=d -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=/usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=/usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF_VARS.fd`. That would start a UEFI based Windows 10 virtual machine, you can easily get your code in there and compile it. It's guaranteed to work at least.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for all your help.